# Blur parent form when child showed

Tags: c#, forms, blur

How to blur parent form when child form showed to user? I using C#. Thanks!

Comment: This is going to be extremely difficult, if not impossible, unless you're using WPF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw semi transparent overlay image all over the windows form having some controls using C# .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503210/draw-semi-transparent-overlay-image-all-over-the-windows-form-having-some-control)