# "Tint" an entire window, or alternative method of making window look inactive

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `winforms` `C#` application that opens multiple dialog boxes. To suit the style of the application, I have removed the default title bars for each window and created my own (with control buttons and drag-to-move function).

The problem that now faces me is that without a titlebar, the user has no way of telling which window is the 'active' window when they are manually moved apart (so they are not overlapping).

In any windows application (that uses titlebars), when you try to navigate away from a dialog box back to the main program (without closing the dialog box) - it wont let you. The border of the dialog box flashes and you hear a windows error sound. Some kind of equivalent visual feedback would be great without needing to have the default titlebars - and tinting an entire window darker seems like it would do the trick nicely.

Something like this in pseudo-code, which would nicely tint the parent window whilst a dialog is open:

```
// tint window now
window.ShowDialog();
// un-tint window
```

I have tried to place a panel covering everything with colour set to 'transparent' (with the intention of later controlling the opacity of the panel) but the transparency does not seem to work. Any other ideas of accomplishing this? Or does anyone have a better suggestion to achieve the same level of visual feedback?

**Summary**:
Is there any way to tint an entire window, or overlay it with a colour? If not, could anyone suggest an alternate method of making the window appear 'inactive'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw semi transparent overlay image all over the windows form having some controls using C# .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503210/draw-semi-transparent-overlay-image-all-over-the-windows-form-having-some-contro)

Comment: @HansPassant that question is exactly what I need. I have created the Utils class with plexiglass function but could you give me an example of how to call it? Sorry it has confused me a little bit :D

Comment: @HansPassant Just a quick pointer if thats okay, and I'll +1 you :D

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a method in forms you want to disable:

```
void DisableForm()
{
    //some fancy color
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Khaki;

    //and disable all controls owned by form, just to be sure
    foreach (var s in this.Controls)
    {
        ((Control)s).Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

and functions which enables back those forms of course.

edit.
also you can set visibility property of controls to false

Comment: This works but doesn't really give the desired effect. Also, my application is dark with white text - so there isnt really any background color I can set to make the form look inactive! :(