# How to draw over a win object?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, system.drawing

I am trying to create a border around two radio boxes with this code.

```
Private Sub form_paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

        Me.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, 533, 130, 92, 58)
    End Sub
```

However I have a flash file set to fill my winform I tried to send the flash file back however that failed. Is there anyway to make a drawing overlay another object if there is how is it done

Comment: use a panel with an orange backcolor

Comment: You cannot paint over a window that's owned by another process.  You'll need a true overlay, another window that's on top of yours and Flash's window.  Core code is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4503371/17034).  Getting rid of Flash completely ought to be your first consideration.