# How to make a panel blur in Winforms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, panel

I am trying to fetch some features through my c# code in winforms inside one panel and it is taking some time .
 I want to make the panel blur and put one progress message or image there and also to disable other controls of the form inside which panel is located,so that user can't use any other controls while features are being fetched and put onto the panel.I can't find any opacity setting for the panel.
How can implement this ?

Comment: To me it doesn't seem like a duplicate. 
However instead of blurring, which will probably hard to implement, why not stacking a semi-transparent panel (blck with opacity of 0.75 or 0.5) on top of the disabled part ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4503371/17034

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove it from your form, you could move your panel somewhere at negative coordinates, put whatever progress bar you want in panel's place and when you are done, put it back and remove progress bar control.