# Disable animation effects for windows with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, animation

I'm trying to disable the "fading" animation in windows which happens whenever you open or maximize/minimize a window.

Of course it can be done manually by unticking the checkbox of **animate windows when minimizing and maximizing**

[image]

I'm trying to do this through the [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx)
This is my call:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, bool pvParam,uint fWinIni);

    private static UInt32 SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;
    private static UInt32 SPI_SETUIEFFECTS = 0x103F;
    public static void Main()
    {
      bool res=  SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, false, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    }
```

`result` value is always **`True`** , so I know the function was successfully called.

But I can't see any results...Windows still keep animating any window I resize.

I compile this as AnyCPU, running as adminstrator on Windows 10.

for @cody gray this is the code (added the ref keyword to the ai paramater and converted the `Marshal.Sizeof(ai)` to `uint).

```
     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     public struct ANIMATIONINFO
     {
         public uint cbSize;
         public int iMinAnimate;
     };

     [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction,
                                                    uint uiParam,
                                                    ref ANIMATIONINFO pvParam,
                                                    uint fWinIni);

     public static uint SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;
     public static uint SPI_SETANIMATION = 0x0049;

     public static void Main()
     {
         ANIMATIONINFO ai=new ANIMATIONINFO();
         ai.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(ai);
         ai.iMinAnimate = 0;   // turn all animation off
         SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETANIMATION, 0,  ref ai, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
     }
```

One last question-if i would like to get back to the original state-which means i want to activate the aniamtions again,what parameter should be changed in order to do this?

Comment: You might have to log out and back in for it to be visible...

Comment: @AustinFrench i'll try it... coming back in a second :)

Comment: @AustinFrench still nothing changed :) i tried to disable other properties-such as disabling the drop shadow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx#spi_setdropshadow
and it did work.. :(

Comment: It animates the frame, no real idea what "fading" might look like.  Use DwmSetWindowAttribute() as shown in [this snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4503371/17034).

Comment: @Slashy: thanks, +1 now, since it makes the question complete.

Comment: To get back to the original state, you need to use `SPI_GETANIMATION` to fill in the `ANIMATIONINFO` struct *first*, save the value of `ANIMATIONINFO.iMinAnimate`, call using `SPI_SETANIMATION` to change the value as you want it, and then restore it afterwards with a *second* call using `SPI_SETANIMATION`. Hopefully that made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the right option when you call `SystemParametersInfo`. The one that controls the minimize/maximize animation effect (labeled in the UI as *"Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing"*) is `SPI_SETANIMATION`.

Using it is a bit more complicated, because the `pvParam` parameter must point to an `ANIMATIONINFO` structure. It is rather pointless, because the struct only has one meaningful member, but that's the way the API was designed. Presumably, the intent years ago was for this to be a toggle for *all* of the shell animation effects, but for whatever reason, that didn't end up happening, and separate `SPI_*` values were used for each of them. You unfortunately picked the wrong one. It is [a long list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx).

Sample code in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ANIMATIONINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public int  iMinAnimate;
};

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction,
                                               uint uiParam,
                                               ref ANIMATIONINFO pvParam,
                                               uint fWinIni);

public static uint SPIF_SENDCHANGE  = 0x02;
public static uint SPI_SETANIMATION = 0x0049;

public static void Main()
{
    ANIMATIONINFO ai;
    ai.cbSize      = Marshal.SizeOf(ai);
    ai.iMinAnimate = 0;   // turn all animation off
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETANIMATION, 0, ai, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
}
```

Note that this is a ***global* setting**, affecting all applications. It is exceedingly rare that an application would ever need to toggle this switch, unless you were making a desktop customization utility. As such, you will require administrative privileges to change this setting.

---

There is *also* the `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED` flag that you can use with the [`DwmSetWindowAttribute` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969524.aspx) to disable transitions when a window is hidden or shown.

The advantage of this is that it is a local solution—you can change the setting only for a single window. But it won't do anything if you are not using DWM (on older versions of Windows), and the minimize/maximize transitions may still be visible. I haven't comprehensively tested the interaction between these two options.

Hans Passant linked you to [one of his answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4503371/366904) that contains an embedded example of how to call `DwmSetWindowAttribute` from C#. Here are the relevant bits:

```
const int DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED = 3;

[DllImport("dwmapi", PreserveSig = true))]
static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hWnd, int attr, ref int value, int attrLen);
```

```
// in the form's constructor:
// (Note: in addition to checking the OS version for DWM support, you should also check
// that DWM composition is enabled---or at least gracefully handle the function's
// failure when it is not. Instead of S_OK, it will return DWM_E_COMPOSITIONDISABLED.)
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
    int value = 1;  // TRUE to disable
    DwmSetWindowAttribute(this.Handle,
                          DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED,
                          ref value,
                          Marshal.SizeOf(value));
}
```

Comment: "unless you were making a desktop customization utility" - or a test automation utility that captures screenshots and wants reproducible, rectangular shaped windows instead of capturing them in the middle of an animation where the window looks trapezoid.

Comment: @Cody Gray it's intetion is to capture rectangular shaped windows for a screen sharing project-one of the tricks that softwares like TeamvViewer use in order to reduce the network traffic :) . so i'll need to use the first code.
There are few simple problems with it when i try to compile-edited my question with it. i'll appreciate if you can help again :)

Comment: @Cody Gray nevermind . Thanks for your amazing answer.