# Is it possible to shut off the transitioning effect of a Window in WPF? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using C# with WPF.

I'm curious is it possible to, either in the XAML or the actual code to stop the transitioning effect of opening a new  WPF Window?

I'm opening another window and it expands from the bottom left corner as if its opening a program for the first time. Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

I want it to have the same effect as when I do something like

```
Content = someusercontrolClassImade
```

I want it to just throw the content on the screen, not have the transitioning effect of a window opening up. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: [Disable animation effects for windows with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395882/disable-animation-effects-for-windows-with-c-sharp) is not the answer to my question, not even sure how it is marked as an answer, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable animation effects for windows with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395882/disable-animation-effects-for-windows-with-c-sharp)

Comment: @Zich Not a duplicate, he is trying to do what I am trying to do but with Systems.ParamInfo, I am trying to simply do it in the code before I do a showDialog or in the XAML somewhere on that window. I also checked out that code and it isn't even working lol.