# How to dim a WinForms form when it is about to open another form and then revert to full legibility when the opened form closes?

Tags: winforms

How to dim Form1 just before it opens Form2, and then when Form2 closes, return Form1 to its original visibility/legibility? How would that be accomplished?

I am not speaking about opacity but about an effect that is like a gray shade has been pulled down, hiding the form, but leaving the borders visible.

(I need to make it so the information on these two forms is never visible on screen simultaneously, and users are confused when I do this using opacity.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503210/draw-semi-transparent-overlay-image-all-over-the-windows-form-having-some-contro

Comment: If the goal is such that… _”the information on these two forms is never visible on screen simultaneously”_ … then … is there some reason you do not simply “hide” form1 before opening form2? Something like… `this.Hide();` … `Form2 f2 = new Form2();` … `f2.ShowDialog()` … `this.Visible = true;` … ? …

Comment: @JohnG: The users are used to seeing windows get grayed out on a couple of web apps when another window is opened above them.  The form going transparent disconcerted them and I think it disappearing altogether would be even worse.